# how to use regular expression replacement in PowerShell

Tags: regex, powershell, replace

`ipconfig | Select-String "IPv4 Address"` returns something like this:

```
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.50
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 172.20.112.1
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.208.1
```

Say I wanted to replace "IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . :" with the empty string using [-replace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators?view=powershell-7.1#regular-expressions-substitutions). How would I do that? Here's what I tried:

```
ipconfig | Select-String "IPv4 Address" -replace "IPv4 Address. . .",""
```

That gave me the following error:

```
Select-String : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'replace'.
At line:1 char:41
+ ipconfig | Select-String "IPv4 Address" -replace "IPv4 Address. . .", ...
+                                         ~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Select-String], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NamedParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SelectStringCommand
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using only `Select-String`, you can can use a capture group to extract the IP-address:

```
ipconfig | Select-String "IPv4 Address.*:\s*(.+)" | ForEach-Object { $_.Matches.Groups[1].Value }
```

- `.*:` matches everything up to the `:`
- `\s*` matches any (zero or more) whitespace between `:` and IP-address
- `(.+)` matches the IP-address (one more more char) and captures it in group 1
- `$_.Matches.Groups[1].Value` outputs the value of capture group 1, which is the IP-address

[This link](https://powershellexplained.com/2017-07-31-Powershell-regex-regular-expression/) gives a good overview about the many possibilities of using RegEx with PowerShell.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
ipconfig | Select-String "IPv4 Address" | foreach { $_ -replace '.*:\s*' }
```

With `.*:\s*`, you match all text up to the last `:` on a line and `\s*` also consumes any zero or more whitespace chars after than colon.

Here is the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=.*%3a%5cs*&i=IPv4+Address.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+%3a+192.168.1.50%0d%0aIPv4+Address.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+%3a+172.20.112.1%0d%0aIPv4+Address.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+%3a+192.168.208.1&r=).

Comment: Since you are in PowerShell, why use ipconfig.exe, vs `Get-NetIPAddress | Select -Property IPv4Address` or `(Get-NetIPAddress).IPv4Address`, then do say this `(Get-NetIPAddress).IPv4Address | ForEach {$PSItem -replace $PSitem, ''}`

Answer (score -3):

Install Git. Start `Git Bash` and use `grep` and `sed` (or `cut` or `awk`):

```
$ ipconfig | grep 'IPv4 Address' | sed 's/.*: //'
```

`s/xyz/abc/` means **s**ubstitute `xyz` with `abc`.

Comment: Yeah, all the Windows fanboys have gone nuts. ;) OK, I'm a Linux fanboy. But I would actually do it that way. And it works, I've tested it. At least on a German computer with `'IPv4-Adresse'`.